# How do I determine which process/application created a file?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to determine which process/application is responsible for creating a file. For instance, an installer is creating/copying files to C:\Program Files\AppFolder. I know I can use FileSystemWatcher to detect when files are created, but not who is doing it. These processes creating files will have just copied the files and will probably still be running.

I've done a good amount of searching, but couldn't come up with anything.

Comment: You could add auditing to the file-system then read the audit log (it's an event log - i.e. in Event Viewer). There's probably a better way though!!

Comment: You mean like this? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399 Problem is it's not available on Home versions. But I'll play around with it anyway. Perhaps there's something in the Registry that does a similar effect.

Comment: Yep, that's the one. It will definitely work - the only issue is that I don't know if the event log entry will have been created when the FileSystemWatcher fires - might be tricky to handle that...